# DIV fill remaining height calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got the following:

```
<div id="modal-container">
  <div id="modal-body"></div>
  <div id="modal-footer"></div>
</div>
```

I'm writing a piece of JS to adjust the #modal-body to fill in the rest of the space available. This is actually more work than it seems:

```
$('#modal-body').css({
  'height': function() {
    // the amount of vertical space we have to work with.
    // this is the height of the container (modalView)
    var containerHeight = $('#modal-container').height();

    // the amount of vertical space the footer takes up
    var footerOuterHeight = $('#modal-footer').outerHeight();

    // we have to also account for the vertical padding of our div
    var paddingTop = $(this).css('padding-top').replace('px', '');
    var paddingBottom = $(this).css('padding-bottom').replace('px', '');
    var marginTop = $(this).css('margin-top').replace('px', '');
    var marginBottom = $(this).css('margin-bottom').replace('px', '');
    var borderTop = $(this).css('border-top-width').replace('px', '');
    var borderBottom = $(this).css('border-bottom-width').replace('px', '');

    return containerHeight-footerOuterHeight-paddingTop-paddingBottom-marginTop-marginBottom-borderTop-borderBottom;
  }
});
```

The problem stems from the fact that we cannot set an "outerHeight" property for our #modal-body so we have to calculate it by taking into account it's own padding, border, margins, etc.

**Anyway, the function above mostly works. My 2 questions are:**

1. Is there any better/easier way to do this?
2. It seems to be 1px off. #modal-container has a scroll bar because of this, and if I subtract an extra 1px, it works. What am I missing? Is there anything else I have to account for other than margins, padding, and borders?

Comment: Also see my updated answer for a pure CSS method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any better/easier way to do this?

Yes, there is.

> The problem stems from the fact that we cannot set an "outerHeight"
>   property for our #modal-body so we have to calculate it by taking into
>   account it's own padding, border, margins, etc.

That's not necessarily, ultimately true. You can use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing), which will force the sizing to include borders and padding, but not margins. So you'll still have to handle margins, but this will save you some work;

```
#yourElement {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Edit:** You can do this using pure CSS; no JavaScript needed. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sex7U/). Here's the basic outline, HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "fluid">Glee is very very awesome! I have margins, too!</div>
    <div class = "fixed">Glee is awesome!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 300px; /*whatever you want*/
    position: relative; /*necessary*/
}
.fluid {
    margin: 10px; /*just an example*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 75px; /*equal to height of bottom fixed-height div*/
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 75px; /*whatever you want*/
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am  trying to use your solution, but I think the containers "position:relative" property is giving my trouble. I need the height and width of the container to be 95% of the screen, and it needs to be centered on the screen.

Comment: @AndyHin Seems to be working fine here: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/7gsVM/).

Comment: Very few people I've talked to are aware of this CSS trick. The magic is setting both the top and bottom properties at once.